# Sequence Convergence under some assumption

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Suppose a positive sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ has a convergent subsequence, namely, $\lim\limits_{j\to\infty}a_{n_j}=\mu$. If for all $n>0$, $|a_{n+1}-a_n|<\frac{1}{n}$, then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_{n}=\mu$. Is that true?

Answer (score 2):

No, consider $a_n := \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{5\log(2)}\log(n)\right)$. This clearly does not converge, but $$|a_{n+1} - a_n| \leq \frac{\pi}{5\log(2)}\left(\log(n+1)-\log(n)\right) \leq \frac{\pi}{5\log(2)}\frac{1}{n} < \frac{1}{n}.$$
However, taking $n_j = 2^{5j}$, we have $a_{n_j} = 0$ for all $j \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Great counterexample. A lot of people think that it should converge, since the sequence is 'Cauchy' (it doesn't have to be though).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: think about the definition of a Cauchy Sequence. where a sequence $a_n$ converges if and only if $a_n$ is a Cauchy sequence.

$a_n$ is Cauchy sequence $\iff \ \forall \epsilon>0 \ \exists N\in \mathbb{N}: \ such \ that: \forall n, m \geq  N: |a_n - a_m| < \epsilon $

Does $|a_{n+1} - a_n| < \frac{1}{n} \Longrightarrow  \ \forall n, m \geq N |a_n - a_m| < \frac{1}{n}$ ?